# Downloading Microsofts knowledge base

Tags: windows

Is there a way to download Microsoft's current Knowledge base? Currently I'm just running a script that trawls through all the KB numbers and grabbing the page (Which is taking a while, currently at KB article 385538 Lol), and then I'm going to collate all the relevent information into a database ... This is only for personal use, so there's no copywrite infringements or anything ... I just need an offline version :D

Comment: No, there is no download of the KB that I'm aware of. Plus, what happens if there is an update to a KB page, and your copy of that page is either out of date, or totally wrong and you don't know about it? I think you're wasting your time to be honest.

Comment: Yeah ... But I do need an offline version ... So any version is better than none Lol ...

Comment: May I ask why you need an offline version? Will you be working in a location with restricted, or no, internet access?

Comment: Yeah ... very bad internet connection ... Doing service desk type work, so if I get stuck, I don't want to be wasting time if the internet has gone kaput

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Ultimately, I don't see there ever being a download of the KB. It's collaborated on by so many people, that it would need to be updated on a very regular basis. That would simply be unpractical to package up in a download. Plus, I would imagine the size of the download file would be immense.

Comment: Hmm ... It's not actually that bad ... Currntly found 130,000 articles, which has taken up 13GB ... But that's the full page download ... Once I've extracted the main points from the pages into a database, I'm expecting it to be less than 1GB ...